# Disable SQS listener in test case run

Tags: java, spring, junit

Spring Boot 2.7.5
JUnit 4.13.2

I have SQS listener in app:

```
@Component
@EnableSqs
@Slf4j
public class SdkUploadListener {

    private final S3Service s3Service;

    @Autowired
    public SdkUploadListener(final S3Service s3Service) {
        this.s3Service = s3Service;
    }

    @SqsListener(value = "${amazon.sqs.sdk-upload-queue-url}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void processMessage(final S3EventNotification message) throws JsonProcessingException {
      ...
    }
}
```

There is simple test case (just want to test Airflow run Dag):

```
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
class AirflowClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private AirflowClient airflowClient;

    @Test
    public void testDagRun() {
        final String dagName = "test-dag";
        final OffsetDateTime logicalDate = OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-08-01T00:00:00.000Z");
        final AirflowRunDugRequest request = new AirflowRunDugRequest(logicalDate, Map.of());
        airflowClient.triggerIngestionDag(dagName, request).subscribe(res -> log.info("Response received: {}", res));
    }
}
```

The problem is that SQS listener starts listening the queue upon test case run.
Is it possible to disable SQS listener for tests?
So I need to use mock for this?

Comment: I had a quit similar Problem. My solution is a ConditionalOnProperty Annotation at the config class. `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "your.property", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)` Under test/ressources I set the property to false so that the Config class is not enabled in test scope.

Comment: @Tr1monster hey, thank you for you prompt reply. Could you please make an answer, in order I can "like" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quite similar problem. My solution is a ConditionalOnProperty Annotation at the config class.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSqs
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my.property", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MyConfig {
}
```

With this Annotation you dont have to change any PROD config. For the use in test scope you can place the config value under `src/test/resources/config/application.yml`.It disable the Config for all Tests.